# JWT Authentication Flow in a Front -End Application?

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, jwt, auth0

I have a  simple CRUD `Java Spring-boot REST API` that connects to `MongoDB` to save/retrieve information about a user's Poker stats. This API is currently not protected by JWT.

The API is shown below:

```
GET - /users/{userId}/games : gets all games relating to a user
GET - /users/{userId}/games/{roundId} : get a specific game relating to a user
POST - /users/{userId}/games/ : create a game
DELETE - /users/{userId}/games/{roundId} : Delete a game
PATCH - /users/{userId}/games/{roundId} : edit a game
```

I am in the process of adding a front-end to the web app , I am learning `JavaScript` but have not yet started learning a specific framework.

I want to validate that the `Authorisation/Authentication` flow I have below is correct/valid before I start on developing the front-end of the application?

```
1. User presses login button on client (e.g express/angular app) - this hits the /login endpoint
2. Auth0 redirects client to /authorise endpoint and displays login page for User
3. Auth0 verifies username and password against DB to check if a valid user
4. If login is successful: Auth0 redirects back to a specific page on the client with a JWT Token
5. Client Application stores the JWT to use in future requests
5. This JWT can then be used to make REST API calls to Java REST API
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's pretty much it, just think of few more things:

- Fetch user, to show username on client
- How are you storing the JWT token on client
- If you want Social logins, it becomes a little more tricky

I would consider a client framework, to have all of this baked in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would you suggest to do a fetch user and storing JWT on the client? I will not need social logins as of yet. Also - as I am using Auth0 I have no need to implement my own back end authorization microservice?

Comment: I would recommend Next or Nuxt depending on React/Vue, both are awesome, more inclined towards Vue